# Valid placement of pebbles on board. Graph theory problem that everyone in my class got wrong

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-writing, computer-science

Can someone please help with this? I’ve worked on it for a few hours but can’t come up with a proof. Thanks!

Consider a $2n\times 2n$ board (namely a board with $2n$ rows and $2n$ columns for a total of $4n^2$ squares) for $n\ge 1$. We place pebbles on squares (at most one per square). The placement of the pebbles ensures that each column and each row contains exactly $n$ pebbles. Consider the coordinates of a placed pebble to be $x : y$, with $x,y \in\{1,2,\ldots,2n\}$, where $x$ is the row number and $y$ is the column number. Show that for any possible valid placement of the pebbles, there is a subset of $2n$ pebbles such that the row numbers are not the same and the column numbers are not the same for any pair of those $2n$ pebbles.

Comment: It's not a good question if you don't provide any context. What have you tried over those several hours? What kind of class is this from? What tools have you learned in that class recently? What happens if you try to apply those tools here?

Comment: Please refer to this thread containing a similar question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3635617/halls-marriage-theorem-2n-rooks-on-2n-times-2n-board?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Here's a combinatorial solution with minimal pre-requisites. Suppose that you're given a configuration $A$ of pebbles. Let the rows and columns of the grid both be numbered from $1$ to $2n$. We define the "configuration obtained by swapping columns $c_1,c_2$" as the configuration obtained on moving every pebble at  $(r,c_1)$ for some $r\in\{1,2,\ldots,2n\}$ to the coordinate $(r,c_2)$ and vice versa simultaneously. On a technical note, we don't require $c_1,c_2$ to be distinct. We define configurations obtained by swapping two rows similarly. Observe that we can find a subset of $2n$ pebbles satisfying the given conditions for the given configuration if and only if we can do the same for a configuration obtained by swapping two rows (analogously columns). Inductively, we can find a subset of $2n$ pebbles satisfying the given conditions for the given configuration if and only if we can do the same for a configuration obtained after a series of row swaps and column swaps.

Suppose that we start with an arbitrary configuration $A$ of pebbles. Let $\mathcal{T}$ denote the collection of all configurations obtained by performing series of row swaps and/or column swaps on $A$. For a configuration $B\in\mathcal{T}$, let $d(B)$ denote the greatest natural number $m\leq2n$ such that $B$ has a pebble on each coordinate in the set $\{(j,j)|j\leq m\}$. Let $A'\in \mathcal{T}$ such that $d(A')\geq d(B)$ for all $B\in \mathcal{T}$. Suppose towards contradiction that $d(A')=m<2n$. Unless otherwise mentioned, we shall henceforth work with the configuration $A'$. If there is a pebble on a coordinate in the set $\{(i,j)|m<i,j\leq2n\}$, then define the configuration obtained by swapping rows $i,m+1$ and then swapping columns $j,m+1$ to be $B_1$. Then, $B_1\in \mathcal{T}$ and $d(B_1)\geq d(A')+1$. This is a contradiction. Hence, at each point in the set $\{(i,j)|m<i,j\leq2n\}$ (Marked with a red fill in fig.), there is no pebble (wrt $A'$). Now, consider the $(m+1)^{st}$ row and column. The $n$ pebbles on the $(m+1)^{st}$ row (resp. column) are present on $n$ coordinates in the set $\{(m+1,j)|j\leq m\}$ (resp. $\{(j,m+1)|j\leq m\}$). So, by pigeon hole principle, there exists $x\in\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ such that there is a pebble at each of the coordinates $(m+1,x),(x,x)$ and $(x,m+1)$. Define $B_2$ to be the configuration obtained by swapping rows $x,m+1$. Now, $B_2\in \mathcal{C}$ and $d(B_2)\geq d(A')+1$. This is a contradiction. Hence, we conclude that $d(A')=2n$. Then the set of pebbles on $\{(j,j)|j\leq 2n\}$ satisfies the given conditions for the configuration $A'$. Thus, a set of $2n$ pebbles satisfying the given conditions in the configuration $A$ also exists as specified earlier.

[image: Fig]

Comment: I'll add an image soon. Please add a comment if anything is unclear/incorrect.